# Jekyll not rendering css from gh-pages

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

I've been fiddling with the css for my Jekyll site recently, but I'm a newbie, and I have ended up breaking it somehow. Now when I go to the website, it just shows the base html, and some large grey divs. Can anybody help me find the problem? I was wondering if it was to do with the way that Jekyll handles css files (I think it generates a new file - main.css - to store all of the css information in one place?), or maybe I did something else incorrectly, I really don't know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this site is very important to me.

Comment: `main.css` doesn't exist anywhere. You have `main.scss`, but that's no good until compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a file encoding problem.

Save ALL your files with **utf-8** encoding with **NO BOM**.

See "*UTF-8 Character Encoding Warning*" in [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/).

Comment: I have checked through my files, and as far as I can see, they're all UTF-8 encoded with no byte order mark... am I missing something? The text editor I have been using is Atom for github, which doesn't support BOMs.

Comment: **css/main.scss** is the only utf-8 with BOM file in your repository. Saving it with utf-8 no BOM resolves the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I have now fixed the BOM issue, however, the site is still not rendering properly. please could you take another look at it to see what's wrong?

Comment: Your file is now utf16 LE with BOM (?)

Comment: Sorry, my fault! I have now fixed it as you said and the site works. Thank you so much! Your answer has been marked as accepted :)